# Can real linear map be defined using only additivity condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Generally, linear map is defined to have the following two properties:

1. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
2. $f(cx)=cf(x)$

If we restrict our discussion to real linear map ($c$ is real), will $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ imply $f(cx)=cf(x)$? It is easy to prove this if $c$ is rational. What about irrational numbers?

Comment: Not unless you add some kind of continuity assumption on $f$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, I don't assume continuity. However, I cannot conjecture a counterexample myself even $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/318523/27978

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can check that $f$ is continuous, then the assertion is true since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. I don't know if $f$ being measurable is already enough, maybe so.

If this is not the case, we can construct $f$ additive but not linear. The idea uses the existence of a Hamel basis of $\Bbb R$ as a $\Bbb Q-$vector space and you can read a sketch of it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Proof_of_the_existence_of_other_solutions), for example.

Comment: +1. Note that this relies on the axiom of choice; for the OP, in ZF (set theory without choice) it is *not* provable that such an "alternate" solution exists.