# Does there exist $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ additive onto function such that $f(F) \subset \Bbb{R}$ has the property of Baire for every $F$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, axiom-of-choice, descriptive-set-theory

Let $F\subset\Bbb{R} $ intersect every uncountable $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$ set.

$B\subset \Bbb{R}$ is said to have [**the property of Baire**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire) if $B=U\triangle M$ where $U$ is open and $M$ is meager.

Does there exist $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ additive onto function such that $f(F) \subset \Bbb{R}$ has the property of Baire for every $F$ defined above ?

---

Edit $1$ : $F$ intersects every uncountable $F_{\sigma}$  set iff F intersects every uncountable closed set.

---

---

Edit $2$: If $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ is additive i.e $f(x+y) =f(x) +f(y) $ then $f$ is $\Bbb{Q}$-linear.In other words $f$ is a linear function if we consider $\Bbb{R}$ as a vector space of $\Bbb{Q}$.

1. $f(x+y) =f(x) +f(y) $
2. $f(qx) =qf(x) $

$\forall x, y\in\Bbb{R} $ and $\forall q\in\Bbb{Q}$

$\underline{ \text{Case }  1}$ : $( f \text{ is } \Bbb{R} \text{ linear}) $

Then $f(x) =ax$ for some $a\in \Bbb{R}$.

Hence clearly $f$ is additive onto map $($ and moreover $f$ is a linear homeomorphism / topological isomorphism $)$.

But $f$ fails to hold the third property mentioned above. For an example ,if we  take $F=\mathcal{B}( \text{Bernstein set})$  then $f(F) =a\mathcal{B}$ doesn't have the property of Baire.

$\boxed{\text{ Required function can't be $\Bbb{R}$ -linear}}$

---

$\underline{\text{Case }2} $: $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear but not $\Bbb{R}$-linear.

Points to be considered:

1. If $g:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) =qx , q\in\Bbb{Q}$ is continuous then $g=f$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ implies $g=f $ on $\Bbb{R} $ i.e any continuous $\Bbb{Q}$-linear map extends linearly on $\Bbb{R}$.

$\boxed{ \text{ So $g$ can't be a continuous on $\Bbb{Q}$}}$

2. A linear map is completely determined by it's action on the basis. So our task is reduced to construct a discontinuous linear map from the vector space $\Bbb{R}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ to $\Bbb{R}$.
3. A non-continuous solution of an additive function ( called ugly function) is non-measurable.

**Conjecture $1$:** $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} $ is $\Bbb{Q}$-linear and non-measurable function. Then $\exists F\subset \Bbb{R}$ closed uncountable set such that $f(F) $ doesn't have the property of Baire.

4. There exists a discontinuous additive function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ satisfying Darboux property ( It can be shown by defining $f$ linealy on a hamel basis of $\Bbb{R}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ and then extending additively on $\Bbb{R}$ )

**Conjecture $2$** : The Darboux property of $f$ ( discontinuous $\Bbb{Q}$-linear function) is sufficient to conclude that $f(F) $ have property of Baire for every closed uncountable set $F$.

5. Any second category (non meager) subset of $\Bbb{R}$ contains a set that fails to have the property of Baire. $[$ Suppose $ A\subset \Bbb{R}$ non meager. Then $A\cap \mathcal{B} $ or $A\cap \mathcal{B}^c$ atleast one of the set doesn't have the B.P otherwise both would be meager and eventually $A$ would be meager $]$
6. $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ is an additive onto function such that $f$ is not injective then  $f^{-1}(y)$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ for all $y\in\Bbb{R}$.

> **Question: Does there exist $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ additive onto function such that $f(F) \subset \Bbb{R}$ has the property of Baire for every $F$ defined above ?**

**[**Here**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429614/483536) is the MO post of this question.**

Comment: Isn't it true that "$F$ intersects every uncountable $F_\sigma$ set" iff "$F$ intersects every uncountable closed set"?

Comment: If additive function $f$ is continuous, $f(x) = ax$, and then it does not have your property.  One method of building discontinuous additive functions uses a Hamel basis.  So perhaps an example can be constructed using transfinite recursion, either starting with a Hamel basis, or constructing the Hamel basis as you go.

Comment: One thing to note is that a nonlinear additive function [cannot be measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318523/additivity-measurability-implies-continuity). Most likely, it cannot be Baire either.

Comment: An observation: if $F$ intersects every uncountable $F_\sigma$, then the same is true for every superset of $F$.  So given $f$, it would suffice to find such a set $F$ for which $f(F)$ is not comeager.  For then there exists a set $A \supset f(F)$ which does not have the BP, and by surjectivity, there is a set $G \supset F$ with $f(G) = A$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I feel that observation could be useful but I don't know how to find  $F$ such that $f(F) $ is non meager ( or comeager is enough as $\Bbb{R}$ is Baire space)? Can you provide any further simplification?

Comment: I don't know how either, but one idea would be to try to arrange it so that $f(F)$ is not dense.  For instance, maybe you can fix some open set $U$, and try to construct a Bernstein-like $F$ that contains no points of $f^{-1}(U)$.  This seems potentially doable, since $f^{-1}(U)$ is likely to be some pathological set that in particular will probably not have the perfect set property, so may not contain any uncountable closed set.