# Under what conditions does a non measurable dense set necessarily intersect every closed uncountable set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory

Let $D\subset \Bbb{R}$ be a dense set.

> Question: Does $D$ intersect every closed uncountable sets?

The answer is negative. As the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ is n.w.dense , it's exterior $\Bbb{R}\setminus \overline{\mathcal{C}}=\Bbb{R}\setminus {\mathcal{C}}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ but it doesn't intersect the closed uncountable set $\mathcal{C}$.

---

Here we want to focus on non measurable dense sets.

---

Under what assumption on the the dense set makes the desirable conclusion true?

---

$A\subset \Bbb{R}$ is called saturated non measurable set iff$$m_i(A) =0=m_i(A^c)$$

Where $m_i(A) $ is the [inner measure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_measure#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20in%20particular%20in,the%20size%20of%20that%20set.) of $A$ and $A^c=\Bbb{R}\setminus A$

For an example [Bernstein set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) is a saturated non measurable set.

> Claim: $A\subset \Bbb{R}$ be a  saturated non measurable set then $A$
> is dense.

> **Lemma:** Let $A\subset \Bbb{R}$ be such that $m_i(A^c) =0$.Then $\forall E\in\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}) $ with $m(E) >0$ we have $A\cap E\neq \emptyset$

**Proof (of the Lemma)**: Assume the contrary that is $A\cap E=\emptyset$.

Then $E\subset A^c$ implies $m_i(A^c)\ge m_i(E)=m(E) >0$.

This contradict our assumption that $m_i(A^c) =0$

**Proof (of the claim) :**  Any  non empty open interval $(a, b) $ is a measurable set with positive measure. Hence from the above Lemmma , it is clear that $A\cap (a, b) \neq \emptyset$.

Hence $A$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$

---

Let $A\subset \Bbb{R}$ be a saturated non measurable set.

> Question:  Does $A$ intersect every closed uncountable sets?

Bernstein set is an example of a saturated non measurable set and Bernstein set intersect every closed uncountable sets.

---

> Conjecture : A saturated non measurable set $D\subset \Bbb{R}$
> intersect every closed uncountable sets.

---

If the conjecture can be proved to be true then it will help me to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4470490/977780) question easily.

---

**UPDATE:**

The conjecture is false.

Let $D\subset \Bbb{R}$ be saturated non measurable set and $F$ be a closed uncountable set of measure $0$.

Then $A=D\setminus F$ is a saturated non measurable set as $A\subset D$ and $A^c\subset F$ and $m_i(D) =0=m_i(F) =m(F) $.

But clearly $A$ doesn't intersect $F$.

---

1. Dense set may not intersect every closed uncountable sets.
2. Saturated non measurable set may not intersect every closed uncountable sets.

> Question:**Under what conditions does a non measurable dense set necessarily intersect every closed uncountable set?**

---

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer is NO, but I don't have time to look into this now, as during the past few weeks and for the next few weeks I'm extremely busy with "day-job" work. However, maybe my comments and references in this [5 February 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ) (minor follow-up [correction](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/QaaZ0eMcoGQJ)) will help.

Comment: If $D$ is a dense saturated nonmeasurable set, and if $F$ is an uncountable closed set of measure zero, then the set $D\setminus F$ is a dense saturated nonmeasurable set which does not intersect every uncountable closed set.