# Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $g(x+y) =g(x)+g(y).$ Then $g(x) = g(1)x$ .

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that 
>   $$g(x+y) =g(x)+g(y).$$
>   How to prove that $g(x) = cx$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}?$

---

The main thing to do here relies upon the fact that such function should be continuous and therefore by natural argument the answer will follow.

Using this
[Additivity + Measurability $\implies$ Continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318523/additivity-measurability-implies-continuity)

Therefore I found out that there is nothing missing in this question.

Comment: This is called Cauchy's functional equation. For proofs, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359183/measurable-cauchy-function-is-continuous

Comment: @Dominik "Cauchy's functional equation" is not a good name for the additivity equation, because it's not the only functional equation that Cauchy studied. If I remember right he also considered such functional equations as $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y).$

Comment: @bof Sure Cauchy also studied other equations, but only the additive one is usually called Cauchy functional equation.

Comment: people say this question miss something that is why they closed it . but the answer to this actually exists . by simply proving that such function are continuous.  sad

Comment: The closure for missing context may or may not have been appropriate, but it's a duplicate of several linked questions, so why nominate for reopen?

Comment: Is that a new way to say duplicate?(duplicate of several linked question) :::)))I discover that link yesterday.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/318587/169852) is excellent, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

For $x_1,....,x_n \in \mathbb R$ we have, by induction, $g(x_1+...+x_n)=g(x_1)+...+g(x_n)$

Let $c=g(1)$.

Then prove in the following order:

1. $g(n)=cn$   $\quad$for all $ n \in \mathbb N$,
2. $g(1/n)=c\frac{1}{n}$ $\quad$ for all $ n \in \mathbb N$,
3. $g(\frac{m}{n})=c\frac{m}{n}$ $\quad$ for all  $n,m \in \mathbb N$,
4. $g(r)=cr$  $\quad$ for all $r \in \mathbb Q$.

Now use that $f$  is measurable to show $g(x)=cx$ $\quad$ for all $x \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: But the last part is the actually interesting part. You write it like this is trivial.

Comment: No, thats not trivial. I left this proof to the OP, which had tried nothing !