# Provided $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, and $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ prove $f$ is continuous everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt...

---

By definition, whenever $|x- x_0| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. Observing that

\begin{align} 
|f(x) - f(y)| &= |f(x -x_0 + x_0) + f(y)| = |f(x-x_0) + f(x_0) - f(y)|  \newline \newline
&\leq \epsilon + |f(y) - f(x_0)| = \epsilon + |f(y-x_0)|...
\end{align}

---

Here I need to choose a delta that can depends on $\epsilon$ and $y$ s.t. whenever $0<|x-y|< \delta$ then the above inequality is bounded by any $\epsilon$.

I'm also, in general, having trouble understanding this concept of continuity on an interval. I believe the structure of the definition is: for any $\epsilon> 0$ and any number $y$ in the interval, there exists a $\delta$ that depends on $\epsilon$ and $y$ such that for all $x$ in the interval and $|x - y | < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

This definition makes me tempted to just choose y to be in the same delta neighborhood as $x$ in the given statement, but that constricts continuity to a small interval.

---

Edit: This question assumes no knowledge of Lebesgue measure theory.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Accidentally deleted it. Edited.

Comment: More general here no continuity is required: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067152/let-g-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-be-a-measurable-function-such-that-gxy-gx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318523/additivity-measurability-implies-continuity

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489356/how-to-show-with-given-hints-that-f-is-measurable-with-fxy-fxfy-imp

Comment: @GuyFsone It is likely that the OP is unaware of measurability, so this question might not be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate of [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation), also [Proving that an additive function $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at a single point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93816/proving-that-an-additive-function-f-is-continuous-if-it-is-continuous-at-a-sin).

Answer (score 2):

Sketch/Scratch work:

- First, prove $f(0)=0$ since $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$.
- Second, prove $f(-y)=-f(y)$ since $f(y-y)=f(y)+f(-y)$.
- Suppose that $|x-y|<\delta$.  Then
  $$
  |f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(y)+f(x_0)-f(x_0)|=|f((x-y)+x_0)-f(x_0)|.
  $$
- Observe that since $|x-y|<\delta$, you have a version of the continuity statement for $x_0$ (replace $x-y$ by $w$ where $|w|<\delta$ if you don't see it).

More details:

Let $\varepsilon>0$, since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, there exists a $\delta$ so that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$.  Fix $x_1$ and let $y$ be such that $|y-x_1|<\delta$.  If you can prove that $|f(y)-f(x_1)|<\varepsilon$, then you have proved continuity at $x_1$.  Since the choice of $x_1$ is arbitrary, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I understand you're work except for your conclusion from the last absolute value, i.e., how does $|f(w + x_0) -f(x_0)|$ give a continuity statement for $x_0$?

Comment: You have continuity at $x_0$ (you don't need to prove it).  This statement allows you to transfer the continuity at $x_0$ to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$
such that  if $|x-x_0| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Since $f(x)-f(x_0) = f(x-x_0)$ we see that this can be written as
for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$
such that  if $|h| < \delta$ then $|f(h)| < \epsilon$.

Now pick some other $x_1$ and note that
since
$f(x) -f(x_1) = f(x-x_1)$, then if $|x-x_1| < \delta$ we must have
$|f(x)-f(x_1)| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in\mathbb R.$ If the function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0,$ then the function $g(x):=f(x+a)=f(x)+f(a)$ is continuous at $x_0-a,$ and so is $f(x)=g(x)-f(a).$ Since $a$ is an arbitrary real number, so is $x_0-a;$ thus $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere.