# $f(x) + f(y) = f ( xy - 2024x - 2024y + 2024*2025 ) ,\forall x,y \in (2024,\infty)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

**The statement of the problem** : Find all monotone functions $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ that verify the following $f(x) + f(y) = f ( xy - 2024x - 2024y + 2024*2025 ) ,\forall x,y \in (2024,\infty)$

**My ideas** (some of them are wrong ) : First of all, by making $x = y = 2025$ we easily get that f(2025) = 0. Thinking about the fact that it is monotonic, I thought that maybe I can prove that it is a constant(proving that it has different monotonies on certain intervals), which would result in $f \equiv 0$, which verifies so it might be the right path. I thought how we can exploit the fact that $f(2025) = 0$ so I thought about the solutions of the equation $$xy - 2024x - 2024y + 2024*2025=2025$$ now the bad part is that $x,y\in (2024,\infty)$ , so there aren't any solutions .The next idea was to think of an additive function, but it was unsuccessful.

Does it seem like a difficult problem? I want to see what ideas and solutions you have, and what helped you to intuit the answer, because maybe this will help me to develop a more analytical way of thinking, or at least make me understand the thought process behind the solution. Thank you very much for all the ideas and solutions !

Comment: The $2024$ in the OP let me think to a recently held (or even ongoing) methematical contest. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: The problem is taken from a contest that was held recently in Romania (not ongoing)

Comment: @LastX can you link the contest ? I'm interested..

Answer (score 4):

We can simplify the RHS as:
$$
f(xy-2024x-2024y+2024\cdot2025)=f((x-2024)(y-2024)+2024).
$$
i.e,
$$
f(x)+f(y)=f((x-2024)(y-2024)+2024)
$$
Now, let $f(x)=g(x-2024)$ for some $g(x)$. This can also be written as $f(x+2024)=g(x)$. Therefore,
$$
f(x)+f(y)=f((x-2024)(y-2024)+2024) \\
\implies g(x-2024)+g(y-2024)=g((x-2024)(y-2024)).
$$
Substitute $u=x-2024$ and $v=y-2024$. Thus,
$$
g(u)+g(v)=g(u\cdot v).
$$
From this, we obtain that $g(x)=\log_a(x), a>0$. Thus, our original function, $f(x)=g(x-2024)=\log_a(x-2024)$ is the solution.

EDIT: Consider the function $h(x)=g(e^x)$, this function is additive, i.e, $h(x)+h(y)=h(x+y)$. Since both $g(x)$ and $e^x$ are monotonic, $h(x)$ is also monotonic. [Additive monotonic functions are linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2671426/1286196). Thus $h(x)=ax,a\in\mathbb{R}$. $g(e^x)=ax$ or $g(x)=a\ln(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please detail more in "we obtain that $()=log(),>0$"?Also we didn't really use the fact that the function is monotone. And should'n $f$ be $c*log(−2024)$ , where $c$ is a real constant ?

Comment: @LastX, In general, $c\log_a(x)$ can be written as $\log_b(x)$, where $b^c=a$.

Comment: actually really makes sense if we consider  c != 0 .  But can you please give more details on how it turned out that the function g is a logarithm from the fact that it is multiplicative. Yes, the logarithm is a multiplicative function, but is the reciprocal also true ?

Comment: @LastX, Yes, since the function is monotonic, we can say that is must be logarithmic.

Comment: @LastX, I've edited the answer explaining how we get that it is logarithmic.