# Does there exists a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I know the existence of non-Lebesgue-measurable sets can be proved using certain representatives of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. So my naive guess is that the answer to the title question is Yes. Not sure how to prove the existence.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Every Lebesgue-measurable additive function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is contiuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/361139), so the Lebesgue-measurable $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the $\mathbb{R}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the $x \mapsto cx$ for $c\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

Since there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}} > \mathfrak{c}$ $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ (every permutation of a Hamel basis induces a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism, and [there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ of those](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759496/cardinality-of-infinite-symmetric-group); on the other hand there are only $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ maps $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$), most - in the cardinality sense - $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ are not Lebesgue-measurable.

Answer (score 1):

The identity function from $\mathbb R$ to itself is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space automorphism of $\mathbb R$. And it *is* Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Actually, you can also modify it arbitrarily on any countable subset of a basis, all in all affecting only countably many points.

Comment: Apologies for the vague question.

Comment: @Berci No, [every Lebesgue measurable additive function is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/361139). So $x \mapsto cx$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ are the only Lebesgue-measurable $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hmm.. I was not entirely sure. However, where is exactly the sloppiness in my reasoning?

Comment: If someone puts Daniel's comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @JosephKabila That someone should be Daniel himself, of course.

Comment: @Berci Changing the value of a basis element $\beta$ affects all points having a nonzero coefficient of $\beta$, and there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ of them (for example all $\beta + \gamma$ where $\gamma$ runs over the other basis elements).

Comment: Ahh, indeed. Thanks for explanation.