# Nowhere continuous function for every equivalence class

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Since our calculus lectures, we know that there are nowhere continuous functions (like the indicator function of the rationals). However, if we change this Dirichlet function on a set of measure zero, then we get a continuous function (the zero function). So my question ist

> Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that every function which equals $f$ almost everywhere (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) is nowhere continuous?
>   Is it possible to choose $f$ borel-measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961745/construct-a-borel-set-on-r-such-that-it-intersect-every-open-interval-with-non-z) for the construction of an $F_\sigma$ set $M\subset\mathbb R$ such that $0\lt m(M\cap I)\lt m(I)$ for every finite interval $I,$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Let $f$ be the indicator function of $M.$ Clearly $f$ is Borel-measurable. If $g(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere, then $g^{-1}(0)$ and $g^{-1}(1)$ are everywhere dense, whence $g$ is nowhere continuous.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant counterexample.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Let $r_1,r_2, \dots$ be the rationals. Let $f(x) = x^{-1/2}, x\in (0,1),$ $f=0$ elsewhere. For $x\in \mathbb R,$ define

$$g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x-r_n)}{2^n}.$$

Then $g$ is a Borel measurable function from $\mathbb R$ to $[0,\infty].$ Note that $\lim_{x\to r_n^+} g(x)=\infty$ for all $n.$

Now $\int_{\mathbb R} g <\infty$ by the monotone convergence theorem. Thus $g<\infty$ a.e. Define $h=g$ wherever $g$ is finite, $h=0$ where $g=\infty.$ The function $h$ fits the bill.

To be sure, there are some things to check, but I'll leave it here for now

Comment: I like your counterexample, I had a hard time deciding which answer I should accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Any discontinuous function s.t. [$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: Additive discontinuous functions are not Lebesgue measurable, so this example  cannot be used for the second part of the question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is it difficult to prove that additive discontinuous functions are not Lebesgue measurable? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45861/show-that-fxy-fxfy-implies-f-continuous-leftrightarrow-f-measur.

Comment: @Severin, suppose f is additive and measurable. The $\mathbb R =\cup f^{-1} (-n,n)$ so there must be some n such that $E \equiv f^{-1} (-n,n)$ has positive measure. This implies E-E contains an interval around 0. [Ref. Halmos 's Measure Theory]. From this and additivity prove that f is bounded on some interval $(-a,a)$, say by M. Now $|f(x)|=\frac 1 n f(nx)| \leq \frac 1 n M$ if n is large enough.  Conclude that f is continuous at 0 and use additivity to get continuity at all points.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy and Martin: Thank you for the references.