# Theorem of Steinhaus

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

The Steinhaus theorem says that if a set $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ is of positive inner Lebesgue measure then $\operatorname{int}{(A+A)} \neq \emptyset$. Is it true that also $\operatorname{int}{(tA+(1-t)A)} \neq \emptyset$ for $t \in(0,1)$? It is clear for $t=\frac{1}{2}$? But in general?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of "positive inner Lebesgue measure" is. However, it should imply that $A$ contains a set $B$ of finite positive measure. Then apply [Cor. 20.17](http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC&pg=PA296) of Hewitt-Ross you mention in the [other answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59772/) to $tB$ and $(1-t)B$ and note that $tB + (1-t)B$ contains an open set, hence so does $tA + (1-t)A \supset tB + (1-t)B$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have not right,  in that way by the Steinhaus theorem $t(B+B)+(1-t)(B+B)$ contain an open set. But is it suffices in order to $tB+(1-t)B$ contains an open set?

Comment: In the corollary linked to you have the result saying: If $X$ and $Y$ have positive measure then $X + Y$ contains an open set. Take $X = tB$ and $Y= (1-t)B$.

Comment: Sorry, you have right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes.**

If $A$ has positive inner measure then it contains a measurable set $B$ of positive finite measure.

Now for $0 \lt t \lt 1$ both $tB$ and $(1-t)B$ have positive measure, hence $tB + (1-t)B$ contains an open set by the result mentioned below. Therefore the interior of $tA + (1-t)A \supset tB + (1-t)B$ is non-empty.

---

In [Corollary 20.17 on page 296](http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC&pg=PA296) of Hewitt–Ross, *[Abstract Harmonic Analysis, I](http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC)* the following general result is shown:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be measurable sets of (finite) positive measure in a locally compact group with left Haar measure $\mu$. Then $XY$ contains an open set.

The proof relies on showing that the convolution $[X]\ast[Y](z)$ of the characteristic functions $[X]$ and $[Y]$ is equal to the function $z \mapsto \mu(X \cap zY^{-1})$; it is continuous; it vanishes outside $XY$; and it is non-zero because $\int [X]\ast[Y]=\mu(X) \mu(Y) \gt 0$, hence $XY$ must contain an interior point.

---

Some background, applications and further links are contained in [this thread here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38902/).

If you read French you may want to have a look at [Hugo Steinhaus](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Steinhaus.html)'s original article *[Sur les distances des points des ensembles de mesure positive](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm1/fm1111.pdf)*, Fund. Math. **1** (1920), 93–104.

In fact, the [entire first issue](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/tresc.php?wyd=1&tom=1) of [Fundamenta Mathematicae](http://journals.impan.gov.pl/fm/) is packed with gems of this sort. Fourteen (!) articles are by [Wacław Sierpiński](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Sierpinski.html).

Comment: Nice one the Steinhaus's paper.