# Steinhaus theorem in topological groups

Tags: harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a locally compact Abelian topological group with Haar measure. It is known that if $B$ is a measurable subset of $G$ of finite and positive Haar measure then $int(B \cdot B)\neq \emptyset$ (Hewitt, Ross, Abstract harmonic analysis I, [Cor.20.17 p.296](http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC&pg=PA296)). My question is whether the interior of $B \cdot  B$ has to contain square of some element of $G$? Thanks.