# For $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon >0$, $\exists$ $(a,b)$ s.t. $\theta(E \cap (a,b)) \geq (1-\epsilon)|b-a|$ ($\theta$ Lesbegue Outer Measure)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In my notes this statement is left unproven. I want to show that for any measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\theta(E)>0$, there exists an interval $(a,b)$ that covers $E$ arbitrarily closely. From the definition of the Lebesgue Outer Measure:

$$
\exists \bigcup_i(a_i,b_i) \supseteq E : \sum_i(b_i-a_i) \leq \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}\theta(E)
$$

And then $\theta(E)=\theta(\cup_i E\cap(a_i,b_i))$, but I'm not sure this helps. Can anyone show me how to finish this off?

Comment: [Here's one way to do it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103306/a-pair-of-lebesgue-measure-questions-concerning-sets-of-strictly-positive-measur).

Comment: Ah. I had no hope of finding that question given its vague title! Thanks!