# High density interval for a positive Lebesgue measure set in higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading [1d case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103306/for-a-set-of-positive-measure-there-is-an-interval-in-which-its-density-is-high?lq=1) saying for $E \subset R$ with $\mu (E) >0$ and $0< \rho <1$ $\quad \exists$ open interval $I$ s.t. $\mu (E \cap I) > \rho \cdot \mu (I)$.

How can we prove higher dimensional analog of this saying:
let $E \subset R^n$ with $\mu (E) >0$ and $0< \rho <1$ then $\quad \exists$ product of intervals $I=I_1 \times ... \times I_n$ s.t. 
$$\mu (E \cap I) > \rho \cdot \mu (I)$$.

Comment: This does not hold with $I$ being a product of intervals. It is true, though, if $I$ is a union of products of intervals, for example.

Comment: @detnvvp There is a cube (product of equal intervals) with this property, by  [Lebesgue's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem)