# Are dense subsets almost nothing or almost everything?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Dense subsets of $[0,1]$ I know have Lebesgue measure $0$ or $1$, but, is there any dense, *uniform* subset of $[0,1]$ with meausre $1/2$?

What I mean with *uniform*: a subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ is uniform if $m(A\cap[a,b])=(b-a)m(A)$ for $0\le a\le b\le 1$. $m$ is Lebesgue's measure. The point is excluding examples like $\big([0,0.5]\cap\Bbb Q\big) \cup \big([0.5,1]\cap \Bbb I\big)$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another twist of the answer is: uniform subsets $A$ are almost nothing or almost everything. $m(A\cap(a,b))=(b-a)\,m(A)=m(A)\,m((a,b))$ implies $m(A\cap B)=m(A)\,m(B)$ for *every* measurable set $B$, due the the same $\sigma$-additivity and regularity of the measure. Now with $B=A$, we obtain $m(A)=m(A)^2$, meaning $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)=1$.

Comment: Simply amazing. Amazingly simple.

Comment: When you set $B = A$, you use the fact that $A$ is measurable, i.e. you show that if $A$ is measurable and "uniform", then it must have measure zero or 1. But you can construct a non-Lebesgue set $E$ that satisfies $m(E \cap B) = (1/2)m(B)$ for all Borel sets $B$. Roughly speaking this is explained here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/non-measurable-sets-via-non-standard-analysis/#more-717

Comment: Yes, but ajotatxe's definition of uniformity assumed measurability by writing $m(A)$ instead of $1/2$.

Answer (score 8):

There certainly is no measurable example: if $E$ is measurable and of positive measure, and $0<\epsilon<1$, then there is some open interval $I$ such that $m(E\cap I)\ge\epsilon m(I)$ (this is an application of regularity, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103306/for-a-set-of-positive-measure-there-is-an-interval-in-which-its-density-is-high)). Now take $\epsilon>{1\over 2}$.

Comment: So let $E=\{\text{irrational numbers in }[0,1]\}$. Is there some interval $I=[a,a+h]\subset [0,1]$ such that $m(E\cap I)<h$?

Comment: @ajotatxe Good catch, I meant "$\ge$" (or "$>$," equivalently in this case) instead of "$=$" - fixed!

Comment: I will remove the "solved" tick, because I'm not sure of my understanding of your answer. I'll think about it.

Comment: @ajotatxe What part are you unsure about?

Comment: I'll think about it :)

Comment: @ajotatxe No, how would it? (And for an easy counterexample take $A=[0, {1\over 3}]\cup [{2\over 3}, 1]$.)