# The construction of a Vitali set

Tags: measure-theory

Can anyone explain the concept of a *Vitali set*? I am not able to understand the construction of the set.

Comment: What is it exactly in the construction that is puzzling you?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have the real numbers, $\mathbb R$. You have the rational numbers inside them, $\mathbb Q$.

We can define an equivalence relation on the real numbers, $x\sim y\iff x-y\in\mathbb Q$. For example $\pi\sim\pi+3$ and $\sqrt 2\nsim\pi$.

Using the axiom of choice we can define $A$ to be a set of representatives for this equivalence class. This means that we choose $A$ such that every real number is equivalent to exactly one element of $A$.

If we do that in the interval $[0,1]$ instead of all $\mathbb R$, this set $A$ is called *Vitali set* and we can show that it cannot be measurable. Of course any set of representatives is not measurable, it is just easier to show that in the unit interval.

Why is the set not measurable? Well, note that if we take the translations $A_q=\{a+q\pmod 1\mid a\in A\}$ for every $q\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,1)$ then we have a countably family of pairwise disjoint sets whose union is exactly $[0,1]$. Since the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant all sets must have the same measure.

We have that $m([0,1])=\sum m(A_q)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty m(A)$. However the sum of a constant positive number can either be $0$ or $\infty$, neither of which is the measure of $[0,1]$. This shows that the set $A$ cannot be measurable .

Comment: Just a small remark: Your answer is obviously correct, but might mislead someone into thinking the choice set is measurable when one does that with all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for your post...but I'm still a bit confused about something. Why do we have a countable family of pairwise disjoint sets when we add a rational number to every element of A? We know that the irrationals are not countable, right? So doesn't A have an uncountable set of elements? Then why/how does adding a rational number to those element in A make the set countable? Also, why is the union exactly [0,1]? I know I'm asking a lot of questions, but I'm still a bit confused..

Comment: @Artus: You don't "add a rational" and suddenly things become countable. Here's a possibly clearer way to define a Vitali set. You define the following equivalence relation on $[0,1]$, $a\sim b\iff a-b\in\Bbb Q$. It's not hard to see that every equivalence class is countable, fix $a$, then $b\sim a$ means $a-b\in\Bbb Q$ and there are only countably many rationals so only a countable of $b$ with this property. So each class is countable, and clearly the union of these classes has to be $[0,1]$ because every element in $[0,1]$ is in some equivalence class.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks a lot. I think I understand it now...I just have one more question about your original post. You say that "the sum of a constant positive number can either be 0 or infinity. But if we add many constant positive numbers, how is it possible to get zero? So if "a" is the length of each set. Then we will keep adding "a"...so how can we get zero unless we have a negativie number somewhere?

Comment: @Artus: Yes, this is the point, the numbers are non-negative. So either they are all zero or the sum is infinite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. This is (hopefully) my last question...we have an uncountable number of irrationals in the interval from 0 to 1, right? And so we have an uncountable number of sets/equivalence classes. That's why the sum is infinity, right? Since there are an infinite amount of equivalence classes...

Comment: @Artus: You are missing the point. The point is that if $A$ is a system of representatives from the $\sim$ defined above, and $q$ is a fixed rational then $A+q$ is a completely disjoint system of representatives, and by varying on all the rational numbers in $[-1,1]$ we certainly cover $[0,1]$ (show that every $x\in[0,1]$ is equivalent to a unique $y\in A$ and $x-y\in[-1,1]$). This is why this is a countable sum. Because the measure is translation invariant $A+q$ has the same measure as $A$, if it's zero, then $[0,1]$ has measure zero; if its positive then $[-1,2]$ has infinite measure. [cont]

Comment: [...] Either way we arrive at a contradiction. Therefore $A$ itself cannot be measurable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How is $\sum m(A_q)=\sum_{i\ge 1}m(A)$?

Comment: @TheSubstitute: Note that each $A_q$ can be obtained from another by a translation of an irrational number. So their measure is all equal. Since there are only countably many of them, and they are pairwise disjoint the equality follows.

Comment: @asaf how do you define a+q(mod 1) and how the union of all $A_q$ equals the set [0,1]

Comment: @Ibs: The easy answer is "by applying the definitions". Every $x\in[0,1]$ has a unique $y\in A$ such that $x-y=q\in\Bbb Q$, so $y+q=x$. So there is some $q'\in\Bbb Q$ such that $y+q'\equiv y+q\pmod 1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila why did we use $q \pmod 1$ if we defined $q$ to be an element of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1)$?

Comment: @Note: What's $0.3+0.99$?

Answer (score 15):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\nm}{\mathcal{N}}$
I have seen at least two constructions that lead to sets called Vitali sets.

In the following consider the Lebesgue measure.

Let $S\subseteq\R^d$. Define an equivalence relation on $S$ by $$x\sim y\iff x-y\in\Q^d.$$ Let $S/\sim$ be the set of equivalence classes determined by $\sim$. Since each equivalence class is not empty, by the Axiom of Choice, we can choose one element of each equivalence class. The Axiom of Choice says that there exist a function $$f:(S/\sim)\to S=\bigcup_{A\in S/\sim}A,\quad \text{ so that }\quad f(A)\in A.$$ Define $$V_d(S):=\{f(A):A\in S/\sim\},$$
i.e. $V_d(S)$ is the set formed by picking exactly one element of each equivalence class and put them all together.

The first construction I have seen is by setting $S=\R^d$ (actually, it was with $d=1$ and $S=\R$). So, let $V=V_d(\R)$. Let's see why $V$ is not measurable.

**Lemma.** *Let $E\subseteq\R$. If $E$ is measurable and $m(E)\gt 0$, then the set $$E-E:=\{x-y:x,y\in E\}$$ contains an open ball centered at the origin.*

The above Lemma is the theorem stated and proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104126/8271).

Notice that the set $V-V$ does not contain any points of $\Q^d$, since $\Q^d$ is dense in $\R^d$, this says that there can't be open balls contained in $V-V$. By the lemma, there are only two possibilities: $m(V)=0$ or $V$ is not measurable. If $m(V)=0$, let $\{q_k\}_{k\in \N}$ be an enumeration of $\Q^d$. You can see that the sets $$V+q_k:=\{x+q_k:x\in V\}$$
are disjoint, measurable, and $m(V+q_k)=m(V)=0$. You can also see that $\R^d$ is the disjoint union $$\R^d=\bigcup_{k\in\N} V+q_k$$ and then $$\infty=m(\R^d)=m\left(\bigcup_{k\in\N} V+q_k\right)=\sum_{k\in\N} m(V+q_k)=0.$$ This is an absurd. Therefore $V$ is not measurable and that's our $d-$dimensional Vitali set.

The second one is by setting $d=1$ and $S=[0,1]$. So, let $\nm=S_1([0,1])$. Let $\{r_k\}_{k\in\N}$ be an enumeration of $\Q\cap [-1,1]$. Consider, again, the sets $$\nm_k=\nm+r_k,$$
they are disjoint and you can see that $$[0,1]\subset\bigcup_{k\in\N} \nm_k\subset[-1,2].$$
Once that we assume measurability of $\nm$ we get measurability of the $\nm_k$, moreover, $m(\nm_k)=m(\nm)$, for all $k$. Thus
$$\begin{align*}
m([0,1])\leq & \sum_{k\in\N} m(\nm_k)\leq m([-1,2])\\
1\leq &\sum_{k\in\N } m(\nm)\leq 3.
\end{align*}$$
If $m(\nm)=0$ we get $1\leq 0$, and if $m(\nm)\gt 0$ we get $\infty\leq 3$. Therefore $\nm$ is not measurable.