# Non measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In first answer of this question [The construction of a Vitali set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137949/the-construction-of-a-vitali-set), how did we came to conclusion that $A$ is not measurable ?

How that series doesn't converge $\Rightarrow A$ is not measurable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a set, $A$, is measurable, then it has certain properties. It's a proof by contradiction. First lets copy the relevant portion

> Why is the set not measurable? Well, note that if we take the
>   translations $A_q=\{a+q\pmod 1\mid a\in A\}$ for every $q\in\mathbb
> > Q\cap[0,1)$ then we have a countably family of pairwise disjoint sets
>   whose union is exactly $[0,1]$. Since the Lebesgue measure is
>   translation invariant all sets must have the same measure.
>
> We have that $m([0,1])=\sum m(A_q)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty m(A)$. However
>   the sum of a constant positive number can either be $0$ or $\infty$,
>   neither of which is the measure of $[0,1]$. This shows that the set
>   $A$ cannot be measurable .

*Assume $A$ is measurable* then it follows, from properties of the Lebesgue Outer Measure, that the union in the first quoted paragraph has measure equal to $1$, and that each set in the union has the same measure, since they are translation invariant (this holds for all sets). Then we use the fact that measure is additive for disjoint sets to conclude that $$m([0,1])=\sum m(A_q)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty m(A)$$ again, we are assuming that $A$ is measurable, however, this sum is impossible, since there is no number $N$ such that $\sum_0^\infty N=1$, so we conclude that $A$ was not measurable.

Comment: Is translation invariant property true for measurable sets only ?

Comment: In the last line you said, again we are using $A$ is measurable, can you explain please, where you are using measurability of $A$.

Comment: @Member No: translation invariance is a property of the Lebesgue outer measure, which is defined on every subset of $\Bbb{R}$. The measurability of $A$ is used to conclude that $1= \sum_i m(A)$ by additivity of the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Crostul, IS that the only place where we are using measurability of $A$?

Comment: @Member Yes, it is.

Comment: @Crostul, okie thank you so much.

Comment: Edited for clarity at that point.