# Function $f$ with $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable but $f$ isn't locally Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to find a function $f$ with $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable but $f$ isn't locally Lebesgue integrable.

---

My approach:

Let $X = [0,1]$ and $A \subset X$ with A is the [Vitali-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137949/the-construction-of-a-vitali-set). So $A$ is not measurable.
Define: $f(x) = \{1 \text{ if } x \in A,\,\,\, -1 \text{ if } x \notin A\}$.

I think that $f$ is not integrable since $A$ is not measureable. But how can I proof this?

And if this is correct, I think I'm finished, since if $f$ isn't integrable, it's also not locally integrable since $X$ is already compact.

And:
$|f| = 1$ (the constant function)

And $\int_X |f| d\lambda = 1$, so $|f|$ is integrable.

---

Thanks

Comment: Review the definition of $\int_Xf(x)d\lambda.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right setup.

*Hint*:

$$\int_{X}f(x)dx = \int_{A}f(x)dx + \int_{X\setminus A}f(x)dx = \int_A 1 dx - \int_{X\setminus A} 1 dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

In point of fact a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $\lvert f\rvert$ is integrable will be integrable (locally and/or otherwise) if and only if it is measurable.

Your $f$ is not measurable because $A=f^{-1}[1/2,\infty)$, and therefore it isn't integrable.