# Does every non null lebesgue measurable set contain a non-measurable subset?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We know that the Lebesgue measure obtained via the usual Caratheodory extension is complete. As such, the subset of every null set is null.

Is it possible to prove that every non-null measurable subset $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ contains a non-measurable subset $B\subseteq A$?

I suppose it must be true, if it has non-empty interior then it must be true (just use an isometry to take a "copy" of a vitali set inside the interval).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287212/non-measurable-subset-of-a-positive-measure-set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non measurable subset of a positive measure set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287212/non-measurable-subset-of-a-positive-measure-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just imitate the usual construction - let $ A $ be a measurable subset of $ \mathbb R $, and choose a bounded interval $ I $ such that $ A \cap I = X $ has nonzero measure. By translating and scaling, we may wlog assume $ I = [0, 1] $. Let $ V $ be a set of representatives in $ I $ for the cosets of $ \mathbb R / \mathbb Q $ intersecting $ X $ (obviously $ V $ may be chosen to be a subset of $ X $, and thus of $ A $), and note that choosing an enumeration $ q_k $ of the rationals in $ [-1, 1] $ and defining $ V_k = V + q_k $ gives that

$$ \mu(X) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(V_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(V) \leq 3 $$

which is a contradiction, since $ \mu(X) \neq 0 $.

Comment: $3$?? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $ 3 = \mu([-1, 2]) $.

Comment: So what is the contradiction?

Comment: Summing countably many copies of a real number can only yield $ 0 $ or $ \pm \infty $, it cannot yield a nonzero real number (as it does in this case).

Comment: thank you very much, I get it now.

Comment: It is not obvious - and in fact wrong - that $V$ may be chosen as a subset of $X$. If $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, then you will not be able to find any representative of the $[0]$ equivalence class in $A$ and therefore also not in $X$

Comment: @FelixB. I said "cosets of $ \mathbb R/\mathbb Q $ intersecting $ X $". In your example the coset $ \mathbb Q $ does not intersect $ A $.

Comment: fair enough - I think I overread the "intersecting X" bit. sorry