# Lebesgue integral w.r.t. complete measure is not complete measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am struggling with proving that the following measure is not necessary complete. I just can't find the way to grab it properly, missing an initial idea.
Suppose we got a set function denoted by
$$\mu(A)=\int_A f(x) \; d\lambda(x), $$
where $\lambda$ is a Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{A}$, $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function and $A\in\mathcal{A}$. I have already proven that $\mu$ is measure on $\mathcal{A}$, but I need to make a comment about completeness. My teacher said that it's not necessary complete. How to grab it?

When I think of negligible set of Lebesgue measure (which is complete), I think of countable sets. But Lebesgue integrals over countable set (set of singletons) will always be zero, which should make measure $\mu$ complete. Another thing could be that $f\equiv 0$ on some interval $I$, that means $\mu(I)=0$, but subset of that interval will also have measure zero.

Comment: what is $a$ Lebesgue measure?

Comment: There are uncountable sets of Lebesgue measure 0.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Yes, for example Cantor set, I forgot about those sets.

Comment: @blamethelag completion of interval-like measure from borel sets to lebesgue-measurable sets?

Comment: So $\lambda$ is $the$ Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal A = \mathcal L(\mathbb R)$ is $the$ Lebesgue sigma algebra. If you take $f = 0$ your measure is certainly not complete. You can generalize it with $f$ null on a set of positive measure.

Comment: OK, so suppose I have a set $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ for which $\lambda(A)>0$. If $f=0 \; \forall x\in A$, that means $\mu(A)=0$. But how do I find subset of $A$ which is $\mu$-non-measurable? Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: Try to use the fact that any set with positive measure contains a non Lebesgue measurable set

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287212/non-measurable-subset-of-a-positive-measure-set for a proof of the property mentioned by @blamethelag.