# Steinhaus Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm having some trouble proving the Steinhaus theorem in $\mathbb{R}^d$:

> Claim: Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be a (measurable) set with positive measure. For some $\epsilon\gt0$, $E-E=\{x-y:x,y\in E\}$ contains the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ of radius $\epsilon$ centered at 0.

We were given the hint to use the fact that $f*g$ with $f(x)=1_{E}(x)$ and $g(x)=1_E(-x)$ is continuous. But I have no idea, how to use this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Given that you know that the function
$$
\varphi(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \chi_E(y)\chi_E(x+y)dy
$$
is continuous. Note that
$$
\varphi(x) = \int_E \chi_E(x+y)dy = \int_{E+x}\chi_E(y)dy = \mu(E\cap (E+x))
$$
Hence, $\varphi(0) = \mu(E) > 0$, so there is a neighbourhood of $0$ on which $\varphi$ must be positive.

Now check that $\varphi(x) > 0$ implies that $x\in E-E$

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just one question: Shouldn't $\varphi(x)$ be the integral of $\chi_{E}(y)\chi_{E}(x+y)$?

Comment: caedmon I think you are correct.

This is the slickest proof I have seen of this fact. The only way I knew was in $d = 1$; one can start by showing that for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$ there is a bounded interval $I$ such that $m(A \cap I) \geq \alpha m(I)$. Can it really be this simple?

Comment: @snarski : It actually takes a fair amount of work to prove that $\varphi$ is continuous (try it!).

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I don't see it being any different than showing that the convolution $f*g$ of two $L^1$ functions being continuous, which as you say is not immediate, but at least I know  how to do. Is that right?

Comment: @snarski : yes, but in that case, you need to assume $\mu(E) < \infty$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Ah, right. So do it for finite sets and then use monotone convergence theorem on $E_n := E \cap B_n(0)$?

Comment: The convolution of two $L^1$ functions is not continuous in general. But the convolution of an $L^1$ and an $L^\infty$ function is, which is enough here.

Answer (score 0):

The method I present in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1344735/18240) easily generalizes to $\mathbb R^d$. It is outlined in exercise 5 of chapter 7 (differentiation) in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.