# Is the Steinhaus Theorem true in $\mathcal{R^n}$?

Tags: measure-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem
This is the theorem I'm referring to, the wiki only states it if the dimension is 1. Is it true in higher dimensions?

Comment: Yes, the theorem holds for any lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613082/steinhaus-theorem-in-mathbbrd)

Comment: There is a proof using convolution of functions. That proof works for $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: The proof in your Wiki link is valid, verbatim, for $\Bbb R^n$ for any finite $n$.