# Apply Fubini's theorem to prove

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a question:

For measurable set $E$ and $F$, with positive measure (in the sense of Lebesgue measure), prove that there is an open interval in the set $E+F$.

I know this is a question from Stein's Real analysis. The point is that I don't know how to prove it using Fubini's theorem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the convolution $\chi_E \ast \chi_F$. (This question has been asked before; I'll try to find it)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86209/steinhaus-theorem-sums-version

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks really a lot. Best regards.