# If A has positive Haar measure then $AA^{-1}$ is a neighborhood of $e$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, topological-groups, harmonic-analysis

I read the following exercise:

Prove that if $G$ is a locally compact topological group with Haar measure $\mu$ and $A \subset G, \mu (A) >0$, then $AA^{-1}$ contains an open neighborhood of the identity $e\in G$.  The hint says something about a convolution being a function of finite type associated to the regular representation of $G$.  I don't know anything about functions of finite type.  Surely there's a more elementary proof?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59769/theorem-of-steinhaus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen the following argumentation, we use inner and outer regularity of the Haar measure. By inner regularity, we may show the claim for a compact $ K \subset A $. Since $ K $ is compact $ \mu(K) $ is finite, so by outer regularity there is an open set $ U \supset K $ such that

$ \mu(K) \leq \mu(U) < 2 \mu(K) $

A basic topological group argument shows that there is a neighborhood of the identity $ W $ such that $ WK \subset U $. We have for all $ w \in W $ that $ wK \cap K \neq \emptyset $ (otherwise we get a contradiction in the above inequality). Thus we have $ W \subset K K^{-1} $.

Comment: very nice! thanks!