# What extra assumption makes this transformation affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Let a vector space $V$ be given.  Let $f:V\to V$ have the property that for all $x,y,a\in V$,
$$
  f(x+a)-f(y+a) = f(x) - f(y) \tag{$\star$}
$$
**Q1.** I'd like to know how weak one can make additional assumptions to guarantee that $f$ is affine, namely that there exists a linear transformation $L:V\to V$, and an element $v\in V$ such that
\begin{align}
  f(x) = L(x) + v
\end{align}
for all $x\in V$.

I think, for example, that if one assumes that $V = \mathbb R^n$, and if $f$ is differentiable, then $(\star)$ implies that $f$ is affine. This makes me think that perhaps one needs a notion of smoothness or continuity in general and therefore possibly a norm?  Also

**Q2.** Is there a common name for the property $(\star)$?

Comment: Is $f$ just a map or a linear map?

Comment: @BISHD Just a map.

Comment: If $f$ were a linear map, you see that the assumption is trivially true and every linear map is a linear transformation for $v=0$.

Comment: @BISHD Yes I understand that.  I am *not* assuming that $f$ is linear.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear. You've asked for extra assumptions ;-) Linearity is one of them. But wait for the analysis experts to help you with analytic assumptions.

Comment: @BISHD lol ok.  I had hoped what I was asking was clear from the context, but I agree it's not entirely clear, so I changed the wording to "how weak one can make additional assumptions."  How's that?

Comment: Sounds great to me, I'm curious about the answer. ;-)

Comment: @BISHD Great!  One might think that such curiosity would warrant an upvote ;) ?  Thanks for the edits btw.

Comment: Already done that! Let's hope for some experts.

Comment: Let $y=0$ and you get $f(x+a)-f(a)=f(x)-f(0)$. Define $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ and you have $g(x+a)=g(x)+g(a)$. So $g$ is additive, and you want to show that it is linear. I would expect that [continuity should be sufficient](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/152632/856), though I haven't checked that the same proof goes through.

Comment: @Rahul Ah thanks!  Does one need to restrict the field over which $V$ is defined?

Comment: Also, @BISHD Linearity is obviously a stronger condition than affineness!

Comment: @joshphysics: I have no idea. As I said, I haven't looked at the proof closely enough to see how well it generalizes.

Comment: @Rahul Ok thanks for the insight.

Comment: Your question is related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186350/cauchys-functional-equation-for-mathbb-rn) on Cauchy's functional equation.