# Given $E_1$, $E_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $m(E_1) >0$, $m(E_2)>0$, show that $\{ x-y: x\in E_1 , y \in E_2\} $ contains an interval using Tonelli's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

The problem is as follows:

> Given two sets $E_1$, $E_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$, with the lebesgue measure $m(E_1) >0$ and $m(E_2)>0$, show that the set $F= \{  x-y: x\in E_1 , y \in E_2\} $ contains an open interval.

Since this problem is introduced right after a chapter on Fubini's and Tonelli's Theorem, I'm thinking using these theorems.

My attempt:

My goal is to show that the measure of $F$ is positive, then it'll contain an open interval. I was given a hint to use convolution, so I try to do the following integratioin of the characteristic functions:

$$ 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{E_1}(y-x)\chi_{E_2}(y)dxdy = \int_\mathbb{R}\left( \int_\mathbb{R}\chi_{E_1}(y-x)dx\right)\chi_{E_2}(y) dy \, (\because \text{Tonelli's Theorem})
$$
$$
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} m(E_1)\chi_{E_2}(y)dy = m(E_1)m(E_2)>0. 
$$
After this I'm stuck. I think I should somehow transform the integral in the first line to the measure $m(F)$, then the proof will be completed.

I'd like to have some hint on this problem to go further.(PS: I'd like to know how to use the Tonelli's Theorem to prove the result, instead of an argument using measure's properties only). Thanks

Comment: Have a look there. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079464/difference-of-elements-from-measurable-set-contains-open-interval

Comment: Convolution of two functions in $L^{1}\cap L^{\infty}$ is a continuous function.  Show that there exists $x$ such that $ \chi_{E_1}(y-x)\chi_{E_2}(y) >0$ for al $y$ in some open set.