# Measurable sets in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable sets in $[0,1]$ such that $m(E)$ is positive.
>   Show that there exist two points $x,y$ in $E$ such that $x-y$ is irrational.

I tried to prove that $f(x)=m(E\cap [0,x])$ is continuous, but I don't know how to show that E has two points whose difference is irrational. Can someone give me some hint?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to prove it by contradiction?

Comment: This is a good idea! Thank you!

Comment: Also related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38902/9464

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x-y$ is rational for all $x, y\in E$, then take any $x\in E$ and note that $E\subseteq S := \{q+x : q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [-1, 1]\}$. Therefore, as $m(S) = m(\mathbb{Q}\cap [-1, 1]) = 0$, we have $m(E) = 0$. The contrapositive of this is that if $m(E) > 0$, then $x-y$ cannot be rational for all $x, y\in E$.

Comment: Seems to me you don't need measure for this, just that $E$ is uncountable.

Comment: @bof That's correct. If all differences in $E$ are rational, then $E$ must be countable.