# If $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ with positive measure, the set $E-E = \{ x-y : x,y \in E \}$ is also measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that the set contains an interval (the Steinhaus theorem), but I can't use this for answer the question, maybe someone have a hint to prove that's true or a counterexample for show that's false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The set of differences for a set of positive Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38902/the-set-of-differences-for-a-set-of-positive-lebesgue-measure)

Comment: @LeB No, that's not the same question at all.

Comment: Oh! sorry! my bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement is false.  Compare the results of [Ciesielski, Fejzić, and Freiling](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1212412875): you can have a subset $A$ of a compact set of measure $0$ (which therefore is Lebesgue measurable) such that $A + A$ is non-measurable.
WLOG take $A \subset [0,1]$.  Let $E = A \cup (10 - A) \cup [100,101]$ which is measurable with measure $1$. Then $$(E - E) \cap [-10, -8] =  A - (10-A) = -10 + (A + A)$$ and this is nonmeasurable.

Comment: Interesting article, of course, it's a counterexample. Thanks.